# How to make Ext.grid.Panel auto fit its parent div size while the parent changes?

Tags: extjs

I have a grid panel as following:

```
Ext.define('Summary', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: ['A', 'B', 'C']
});

var summaryStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    model: 'Summary',
    data: summaries
});

Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    renderTo: summaryNode,
    store: summaryStore,
    layout: 'fit',
    resizable: true,
    title: 'Application Users',
           columns: [{
                text: 'A',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'A'
            }, {
                text: 'B',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'B'
            }, {
                text: 'C',
                flex: 1,
                dataIndex: 'C'
            }]
});
```

And the `summaryNode` is a `div`, my application has CSS that changes the `summaryNode` to bigger, but the grid panel i created in it doesn't change its size accordingly.

What am i supposed to do with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, try to set `resizable` config param to `true`! If it's not fit your request, then handle `onWindowResize` event.

```
Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function() {
    var w = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().width;
    var h = Ext.getBody().getViewSize().height;
    // give an id to the grid panel, lets say 'sample-grid'
    Ext.getCmp('sample-grid').setSize(w, h);
})
```

Comment: Cool, It's really what i want. Thanks very much. But still one thing made me uncomfortable. Once i used JQuery to trigger the window resize event as `$(window).trigger('resize')`, Ext.EventManager didn't receive anything. Only the size of window indeed changed would trigger `Ext.EventManager`. So i get my workaround like `$(window).on('resize', function(e) {
                var w = $('#summary').width();
                var h = $('#summary').height();
                Ext.getCmp('summaryGrid').setSize(w, h);
            });`

Comment: Also, I got an email today which it was JavaScript `matchMedia` method. `matchMedia` something similar CSS's media query. If you interest check in Mozilla MDN network or http://us5.campaign-archive1.com/?u=ea228d7061e8bbfa8639666ad&id=3732d5c95d&e=db1cd31664